# How to have random image each refresh for one style sheet, but go away upon choosing another stylesheet?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, wordpress

I'm currently working on my own Wordpress theme. I thought it'd be cool to have a dropdown box in the sidebar in which you can choose different themes, and it'll change the page background, border colors, etc a bit.

The thing is, for one theme (the default one) I have Javascript in my header.php file where the header image will change each refresh. I want this header image to go away when switching stylesheets, but it just overlaps the other one. How do I change this?

If you want to see for yourself, the box is in the right sidebar under the blue buttons. This is my testing website. Ignore the 000webhost stuff.

http://trainman1405.site11.com/wordpress/

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The general solution here is to define all of your styles in one sheet, but namespace them so you can simply change the `class` on the `body` and the new styles will take effect. (You could also define them in separate sheets, using the namespaces, and simply reference every sheet in your `<head>`.)

For example, some CSS:

```
body a { color: #00f; } /* default */
body.green a { color: #090; }
body.red a { color: #f00; }
```

And then when you want to change it (using jQuery, although plain Javascript could do this job too):

```
$('#theme_select').change(function()
{
   $('body').removeClass('green').removeClass('red'); // remove existing classes
   $('body').addClass($(this).val()); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you could use a javascript library its called jquery. You could use that to hide and display a new image e.g

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">



function piczotheme() {

$("defualttheme").hide()
$("mountaintheme").hide()

//and then show load add your picture

$('#defualt').css("background-image", "url(url of the picture)");




}


</script>
```

and then you have to set up a button or something to trigger this effect

so...

```
<button onclick="piczotheme()"> click </button>
```